# Getting wrong output in fetching data?

Tags: reactjs

I want to ask you on my react program. First I need to get user data and then load event by user ID. Sometimes, data are not fetching (mainly after reload page), but sometimes data are fetched. And then I am getting strange output:

[image]

Why second fetched data are named as "undefined"?
Do you have any ideas to improve this code and fetching data ?

My code:

```
const [historyTeams, setHistoryTeams] = useState([]);
const [event, setEvent] = useState([]);
const userId = useParams().userId;


    const loadUserData = (userId, token) => {
        getUserData(userId, token).then(data => {
            if (!data.error) {
                setHistoryTeams(data.historyTeams);
            }
            else {
                setStatus({...status, error: data.error});
            }
        });
    }

    const loadEventData = (eventId) => {
        getEvent(eventId).then(data => {
            if (data.error) {
                console.log(data.error);
            }
            else {
                setEvent({...event, data});
            }
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        loadUserData(userId, token);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(historyTeams){
            for(let i = 0; i < historyTeams.length; i++){
                loadEventData(historyTeams[i].eventId);
            }
        }
    }, []);
```

Comment: what the hook useParams() does? and try to display it by using console.log I think it's undefined.

Comment: it is userId .. output of this line is OK

Answer (score 0):

Your userId is undefined, this is why you got undefined in the key of your object.

Comment: ID is OK, because this is getting by params

Comment: I'm talking about userId in userEffect, I can't see any userId.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add line with userId .. I edited my main post with code.